# Help with a proof regarding simple functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is

> If $f>g≥0$, then there exists non-negative measurable simple functions $f_k↗f$ s.t. $f_k≥g$ for all $k$.

My attempt. Using a theorem in my text book

> For every non-negative function $f$, there exists a sequence $f_k$ of non-negative simple functions s.t. $f_k↗f$.

Suppose $g_k$ is a sequence of non-negative simple function s.t. $g_k↗g$. For any $k$, $f-g_k>0$, then there exists non-negative simple functions $h_j↗f-g_k$, thus $h_j+g_k↗f$ with respect to $j$.

But I got stuck here. Sine $g_k\le g$, I cannot conclude $h_j+g_k \ge g$. Hope someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: But $g$ is not a simple function. If by the same argument, $h_j+g$ is not a simple function.

Comment: I don't believe the result. Consider $f(x) = g(x) = x$. Any function that is less than $f$ is less than $g$, and $f$ is not simple. You need a strict inequality, no?

Comment: Sorry. That's my mistake. It should be $f>g$.

Comment: Are you sure that a theorem in your textbook says: "For every non-negative function $f$, there exists a sequence $f_k$ of non-negative measurable simple functions st. $f_k↗f$" ??  Please, note that if $f$ is not mensurable then there is no such sequence $f_k$ of non-negative measurable simple functions st. $f_k↗f$.

Comment: Even with the restriction to measurable functions, there are still problems, as triple_sec shows. Even if we were to restrict ourselves to a compact domain, $f(x) = 1/x +x$ and $g(x)= 1/x$ would still be a counterexample on $[0, 1]$. So I think we actually need a compact domain and continuous functions. Can we get some confirmation that this is the correct problem statement: "given an interval [a, b] and continuous functions on that interval, $f$ and $g$ with $f>g\geq 0$, show that there are simple functions $\{f_k\}$ such that $g < f_k \leq f$ and $f_k \nearrow f$"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. To see this, let
\begin{align*}
f(x)\equiv&\,\frac{1}{x},\\
g(x)\equiv&\,\frac{1}{x^2},\\
\end{align*}
for each $x\in[1,\infty)$. Clearly, $f>g>0$. I claim that there exists no simple measurable function $\varphi:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f\geq\varphi\geq g$ pointwise (let alone a sequence of such functions). To see this, suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $\varphi$ is a such a function. Then, there exist some $N\in\mathbb N$, some measurable subsets $A_1,\ldots, A_N$ of $[1,\infty)$, and distinct non-negative numbers $c_1,\ldots,c_N$ such that $$\varphi=\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n\mathbb 1_{A_n}.$$ It is without loss of generality to assume that $A_1,\ldots,A_N$ are not empty and disjoint. Because of this and the fact that $\varphi\geq g>0$, it must be the case that $c_1,\ldots,c_N$ are all positive and $A_1,\ldots,A_N$ form a partition of $[1,\infty)$. Let $\varepsilon\equiv\min\{c_1,\ldots,c_N\}>0$. Because of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, there exists some $x\in[1,\infty)$ such that $f(x)<\varepsilon\leq\varphi(x)$, which contradicts $f\geq\varphi$.

Comment: What if we restrict $f$ and $g$ to have compact support? (Or just $f$ since $f > g \geq 0$ would imply $g$ has it, too.)

Comment: @user46944 It doesn't work. Let the space be $[0,1]$ and
\begin{align*}
f(x)\equiv\begin{cases}2&\text{if $x=0$,}\\x&\text{if $x\in(0,1)$,}\\2&\text{if $x=1$,}\end{cases}\end{align*}
and $g(x)\equiv x^2$ for each $x\in(0,1]$ and $g(0)\equiv 1$. With the notation as above, let $\varepsilon\equiv\min\{c_1,\ldots,c_N,1/2\}\in(0,1)$ (since $0<g\leq\varphi$). But then $$\varepsilon/2=f(\varepsilon/2)\geq\varphi(\varepsilon/2)\geq\varepsilon,$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @user49644 I conjecture that it works for _continuous_ functions with compact support.